# How can I hide categories and tags in quick view in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tags, hide, categories

How to hide categories and tags in quick view? I am using WPC Smart Quick View 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about [this plugin](https://wpclever.net/downloads/smart-quick-view). When I visited their website, I saw a [live preview page](https://demo.wpclever.net/woosq/).

I would say the easiest way to hide that meta data would be through CSS. So when I used the Developer Tools of my browser, I was able to figure out the popup modal's id is `woosq-popup`

[image]

And on inspecting the Categories element, I found the class name of its container to be `product_meta` :

[image]

So a custom CSS code like this would resolve the issue:

```
#woosq-popup .product_meta {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Your code works very well - the categories and tags are no longer visible in the WPC Smart Quick View and that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @user15428339 Glad to help! :)